# external js file / unobtrusive js not working but there is no error in console

Tags: javascript, asp.net, unobtrusive-javascript

I have an external JavaScript file, the inline JavaScript works fine but when I separate it (unobtrusive), it doesn't work and doesn't show an error either.

I am using Visual Studio Web Developer Express 2010. Please see my code.

HTML

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <br />
     <button id="btnSave" type="button" style="width:300px; height:200px;"> SAVE           </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

ASPX head

```
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/javascript_01.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

External JS

```
        /// <reference path="~/Scripts/libframeworks/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js" />

(function () {
    $('#btnSave').mouseover().css("background-color", "Blue");
    $('#btnSave').mouseleave().css('background-color', 'gray');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never run, you need to call the function using `()`, so it becomes an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), and the code inside it will be executed.

Remember to add jquery, before your script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Your External JS:

```
(function ($) {
    $('#btnSave').mouseover().css("background-color", "Blue");
    $('#btnSave').mouseleave().css('background-color', 'gray');
})(jQuery); //You need to call the function :)
```

Comment: I added () before the semicolon of js function in external file but there is error encountered : $ is not defined. . . am I referencing correctly to the jquery js file? see my code External js reference path

Comment: Check edited answer, Probably you're using other framework that make use of $, so just pass jQuery as a parameter.

Comment: error now is jQuery undefined. I'm only using jquery 2.1.4 js file with one web Form file.

Comment: If jquery is undefined, you never included it, check my answer, and add jquery script before including your external JS

Comment: I drag and drop the jquery file in the external js and also to the aspx, I added alert message in external js and it works , no error in console but the mouseover jquery function is not working.